# mfc list control

Tags: list, mfc

Имеется диалоговое окно в нём находится list control. В него необходимо ввести данные и затем открыть.
Zadanie -класс диалога, listb - переменная ctrl list.
Код кнопки вызывающей диалоговое окно:

```
Zadanie dll ;
ModifyStyle(LVS_TYPEMASK, LVS_REPORT);
dll.Zadanie::listb.InsertColumn(0, L"f", LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
dll.Zadanie::listb.InsertColumn(1, L"i", LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
dll.Zadanie::listb.InsertColumn(2, L"o", LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
dll.Zadanie::listb.InsertColumn(3, L"Year", LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
dll.Zadanie::listb.DeleteAllItems() ;
Student* st = GetDocument()->m_list.GetFirst();
for (; st != NULL; st = GetDocument()->m_list.GetNext())
{
int nPos = dll.Zadanie::listb.InsertItem(dll.Z adanie::listb.GetItemCount(), st->Getf(), 0);
dll.Zadanie::listb.SetItemText(nPos , 1, st->Geti());
dll.Zadanie::listb.SetItemText(nPos , 2, st->Geto());

CString sYear;
sYear.Format(L"%d", st->GetYear());
dll.Zadanie::listb.SetItemText(nPos , 3, sYear);
dll.Zadanie::listb.SetItemData(nPos , (DWORD_PTR)st);
}
dll.DoModal();
```

Ошибка:
Вызывается исключение из-за m_Hwnd и this равного null на insertcolumn.
Я подумал, что проблема в том что переменной контрола не сопоставлено его ид. Я хотел бы узнать способ сделать это.
Я знаю что это делается в программе после вызова DoModal в DoDataExchange.

```
`DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, listb);`
```

Но мне надо сделать это до domodal.

Comment: Ошибка не меняется. В dodataexchange вызывается DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, listb); и он вызывается после oninitdialog. Перенести этот код в dodataexchange не могу нет доступа к переменной m_list.

Comment: Хорошо. Код кнопки.void CursuchView::OnComplete()
{
 Zadanie dll ;
 dll.DoModal(); }  Код DoModal().{
 OnInitDialog();
 // TODO: добавьте специализированный код или вызов базового класса

 return CDialog::DoModal();
} Код OnInitDialog():  {CDialog::OnInitDialog();
 ModifyStyle(LVS_TYPEMASK, LVS_REPORT);
 Zadanie::listb.InsertColumn(0, L"f", LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);} Ошибка та же когда пытаюсь сделать insertcolumn или CDialog::OnInitDialog() то исключение m_hwnd null

Comment: Я всё понял. осталась одна проблема m_list я получаю с помощью функции getdocument. Как мне получить его в oninitdialog()?

Comment: Глупый вопрос. При попытке использования оператора =. Появляется нелепая ошибка. 
 dll.Zadanie::list.operator=(GetDocument()->m_list);
 dll.Zadanie::list = GetDocument()->m_list;
 При попытках сделать это появляется ошибка:                        
 List::operator=: должна возвращать значение. Код переоперделенной операции:   List& operator=(List& rhv)
 {
  Clear();
  CopyFrom(rhv);
 }

Comment: Разобрался Разобрался Разобрался